# Prove, if $h(u,v)=f(\sin u + \cos v)$ then $h_u \sin v +h_v \cos u = 0.$

Tags: real-analysis

> Prove:
>
> If $$h(u,v)=f(\sin u + \cos v)$$ then $$h_u \sin v +h_v \cos u = 0.$$

Setting $f(\sin u + \cos v)= f(x)$,

$$h_u = \frac{\partial h}{\partial u} =  \frac{\partial f}{\partial x}\frac{d x}{d u} = \frac{\partial f}{\partial x} \cdot \cos u,$$

$$h_v = \frac{\partial h}{\partial v} = \frac{\partial f}{\partial x}\frac{d x}{d v}= \frac{\partial f}{\partial x} \cdot (- \sin v);$$

so to prove

$$h_u \sin v +h_v \cos u = 0 $$

we observe that

$$ \left( \frac{\partial f}{\partial x} \cdot \cos u \right) \sin v + \left(  \frac{\partial f}{\partial x} \cdot (- \sin v) \right) \cos u =0, $$

$$\frac{\partial f}{\partial x} \cdot 0  = 0 $$
$$\text{True}$$

.

Is this right way to proceed? Is there anything to add to this? Are the notation between partial and derivative correct?

Any input is much appreciated

Comment: I edited your question to make the flow of the logic a little more clear.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're trying to prove $A=B,$ then it is NOT correct to proceed as follows.
$$
A = B
$$
Therefore
$$
C = D
$$
(since $C$ is the same as $A$ and $B$ is the same as $D$).
Therefore
$$
E=0
$$
(for the same reason).
$$
\text{True}
$$
I've seen students format things like this hundreds of times. I've never heard of its being taught, yet it persists.

One way of proving $A=B$ is to write
$$
A = X = Y = Z = \cdots = P = Q = R = S = B.
$$
Another way is to write
$$
A = B \text{ if blah blah blah blah } \ldots
$$
and then try to prove blah blah blah blah.

So you could write this:
$$
h_u = \frac{\partial h}{\partial u} =  \frac{\partial f}{\partial x}\frac{d x}{d u} = \frac{\partial f}{\partial x} \cdot \cos u
$$
$$
h_v = \frac{\partial h}{\partial v} = \frac{\partial f}{\partial x}\frac{d x}{d v}= \frac{\partial f}{\partial x} \cdot (- \sin v)
$$
Therefore
$$
h_u \sin v + h_v \cos u =\left( \frac{\partial f}{\partial x} \cdot \cos u\right) \sin v + \left( \frac{\partial f}{\partial x} \cdot (- \sin v) \right) \cos u =0.
$$

Answer (score 2):

***Close!***

The procedure is *essentially* correct, ***but . . .***

There are a few improvements which have been made, to wit:  it's probably better, as Michael Hardy observed, not to state your desired result before it's proof without some explanatory words lest your reasoning seem circular.  My other remark goes to the

***notation:*** it would most likely be better to write

$\dfrac{df}{dx} \dfrac{\partial x}{\partial u}, \tag 1$

rather than

$\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial x} \dfrac{dx}{du}, \tag 2$

etc., since $f(x)$ is a function of the *single* variable $x$, which in turn depends on the *two* variables $u$ and $v$; the revised notation which I presented here is in accord with the customary usage of $d/dx$ *versus* $\partial/\partial u$ and so forth.

Comment: $-1$ since it is not correct. See my answer.

Comment: @MichaelHardy:  a caution against MSE'ing it when too sleepy!